# Is it a good practice to use serializer as query parameters validators?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Serializer would not be used for its intended purpose of creating some django model but it would be used for query parameters validation, creation of filtering query to elasticsearch, swagger documentation describing API.

```
from rest_framework import views, serializers, fields
from rest_framework.response import Response


class TestQueryParams(serializers.Serializer):
    id = fields.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    date = fields.DateField(format='%Y%m%d')


class TestView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        qp = TestQueryParams(data=request.query_params)
        qp.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        # parameters would not be used to create some model
        # but they would be used to get data
        return Response({'some': 'data'})
```

Comment: Django already has this builtin - this is called forms : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#using-forms-to-validate-data

Comment: It looks like there is no way of generating swagger documentation automatically from forms.

Comment: Mmm no indeed, I'm afraid I missed that part...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Definitely a good practice, since the serializer will automatically validate the fields, and raise the right exception if required.

The alternative is to either manually define these validations in the view, or worse - have your APIs return 500 server errors whenever an incorrect input is sent.

Comment: Problem is that if I use serializer I have to hack swagger because documentation for serializer will be generated only for PUT, PATCH, POST methods as can be seen in https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.4/rest_framework/schemas.py#L567

Comment: If you are using `drf-yasg`, you can annotate your API calls with `@swagger_auto_schema(query_serializer=MyQuerySerializer)`, which will show up in the Swagger/OpenAPI schema. [Docs](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/openapi.html) are a bit hard to find, but it works great.

Comment: I believe the 400 status code would be preferable instead of 500.

Comment: Having your API return 500 errors is not a good practice. When you know which errors might occure and can check for them, you should have your API return the correct error code and message. In this case it would be status_code_400.